# Elasticsearch regexp search gives empty result

Tags: python, elasticsearch

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "full_text": {
                "value": "\bhello\b"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ES query that has to return documents that have an exact match in the 'full_text' field using regexp. The word "hello" appears in many documents but the query result is empty:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
};
```

Why do I get this empty result?

Comment: You said that the regex search is looking for exact matches -- this usually means the whole string has to match, not just a part of it. If your document's `full_text` field has any more content, for example "Hello Kirk", it wouldn't match.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I think I need to find another way to solve my problem, not using regexp